# How to work on tablesorter hidden rows

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

How can I construct jquery selector to get "hidden" (they dont have hidden attribute) rows in tablesorter with paging.

```
$('#table tr');
```

This code shows only visible data.

```
var table = $("#table");
table.tablesorter({headers: { 1: { sorter: false }, 2: { sorter: false }}})
.tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager")});
```

Comment: how would you define *hidden* rows? share your markup please

Comment: Please provide more source code.

Comment: are you sure those rows are still there and weren't removed? `$('#table tr');` will get all rows, doesn't matter if they are visible or not

Comment: I don't know where that data is stored. That's my question, how can I find them.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution for this problem:

```
var rows = $('table')[0].config.rowsCopy;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:hidden` filter in selector. Try

```
$('#table tr:hidden');
```